# Проверка на заполненность переменной Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
for x in users:

    # Переходим по аккаунтам

    browser.get(x)

    # Проверка на Группу

    rang = browser.find_element_by_class_name('row_data')

    if rang.text == "Пользователи":
        # Нажимаем на кнопку "отправить сообщение"

        sendmassage = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pm_button')

        sendmassage.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        # Заполняем тему

        title = browser.find_element_by_name('msg_title')

        title.send_keys('По поводу лидерки')


        # Заполняем сообщение

        message = browser.find_element_by_name('Post')

        message.send_keys('https://vk.com/samp_portland')

        # Отправляем сообщение

        submit = browser.find_element_by_name('send_msg')

        submit.click()


    else:
        continue
```

Есть переменная sendmassage Надо сделать так, что если она пустая, то цикл "for x in users" продолжился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ребята, надо читать доки и туториалы по тем технологиям, которые вы используете!

Питон не вкурсе о ошибках возможных в Селениуме, поэтому на:

```
except NoSuchElementException:
```

будет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А всё потому, что нужно импортировать библиотеку селениума, в которой будут описаны возможные ошибки Селениума

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

except WebDriverException:
```

И тогда `try except` сработает как надо!

В вашем коде:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    sendmassage = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pm_button')
except WebDriverException:
    continue
```

А пустой `except` не стоит использовать!

Вот тут почитайте о принципах `try except` - https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html

А тут о возможностях Selenium - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Пункт 7.1 о except в selenium

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отловить с помощью конструкции try catch

```
try:
    sendmassage = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pm_button')
except:
    continue
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, Пишет ошибку `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .pm_button`

Comment: попробуйте обернуть в try catch

Comment: отпишитесь, помогло ли вам данный код

Comment: Да, сейчас попробую.

Comment: не помогло вот такой код у меня `try:
            sendmassage = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pm_button')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
        else:`
Подчёркивает `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: в else прописал сценарий "если есть кнопка"

Comment: тогда просто except оставьте, без NoSuchElementException